# console.log not displaying edited input using PUT method

Tags: angular

I have fetched the data into the input fields (title and body) from this source (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts). Now I want to be able to change the text in the title or body, so that whenever I console.log() it should display changed title and/or body. I tried to do it but in the network it shows two errors:

[Here is the error messages I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFlNs.png)

Here is my forms.component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormService } from './forms.service';
import { form } from './form-interface';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-forms',
  templateUrl: './forms.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./forms.component.css']
})
export class FormsComponent implements OnInit {

  formsUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
  forms: any;
  title: any;
  body: any;
  id: any;
  post: form =  {
    "userId": 0,
    "id": 0,
    "title": "",
    "body": ""
  };

  constructor(private formService: FormService ,private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router, private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id=this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

    this.formService.getForms(this.id).subscribe(
      (posts: any) => {
        this.forms = posts[0];
        console.log(posts);
        this.title = this.forms.title;
        this.body = this.forms.body;
      }
    );
  }

  editForm(){
        fetch(this.formsUrl + "/" + this.post.id, {
          method: 'PUT',
          body: JSON.stringify({
            id: this.post.id,
            title: this.post.title,
            body: this.post.body,
            userId: this.post.userId
          }),
          headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
          }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => console.log(json));
      }
}
```

And here is my HTML file:

```
<div class="forms container">
  <form #postForm="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="title">Title</label>
          <input [(ngModel)]="title" 
          name="title"  
          id="title" 
          type="text" 
          class="form-control"
          >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="body">Body</label>
        <textarea [(ngModel)]="body" 
        name= "body" 
        id="body" 
        cols="30" 
        rows="10" 
        class="form-control"
        ></textarea>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-success" (click) = editForm()>Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `httpClient` instead of the `fetch` and that is recommended by angular:

```
editForm(){
   this.http.put(this.formsUrl + "/" + this.post.id, {
      id: this.post.id,
      title: this.post.title,
      body: this.post.body,
      userId: this.post.userId
   }).subscribe(
      (response) => {
         console.log(response);
      },
      (error) => {
         console.log(error);
      });
}
```

keep in mind that you don't need to specify the header `Content-Type="application/json"` as it's the default header content type

and always for the best practice don't ever forget to `unsubscribe` after component destroyed using `ngOnDestroy` life cycle hook, angular clean automatically the subscriptions to Observables provieded by angular for example like the `params`, `queryParams` in `ActivatedRoute`, but if you subscribe to a custom Observable or `http` Observables you need to make sure that subscriptions cleaned or you will get performance issues, so the code should be:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormService } from './forms.service';
import { form } from './form-interface';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-forms',
  templateUrl: './forms.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./forms.component.css']
})
export class FormsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  dataSubscription: Subscription; 

  formsUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
  forms: any;
  title: any;
  body: any;
  id: any;
  post: form =  {
    "userId": 0,
    "id": 0,
    "title": "",
    "body": ""
  };

  constructor(private formService: FormService ,private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router, private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id=this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

    this.formService.getForms(this.id).subscribe(
      (posts: any) => {
        this.forms = posts[0];
        console.log(posts);
        this.title = this.forms.title;
        this.body = this.forms.body;
      }
    );
  }

  editForm(){
     this.dataSubscription = this.http.put(this.formsUrl + "/" + this.post.id, {
        id: this.post.id,
        title: this.post.title,
        body: this.post.body,
        userId: this.post.userId
     }).subscribe(
        (response) => {
           console.log(response);
        },
        (error) => {
           console.log(error);
        });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
     if(this.dataSubscription){
        this.dataSubscription.unsubscribe();
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. Unfortunately, the "PUT https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/0 500" error still remains, and it does not change the 'title' and 'body' values.

Comment: you need to modify your url, because there is no post with id 0 in jsonplaceholder posts data, it should be `jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1` the post id should be 1+

Comment: okay, the error I mentioned above is cleared, but the last problem remains that whenever I edit 'title' or 'body' and click submit, it always (for any user with any id) returns in the console.log  body: ""
id: 1
title: ""
userId: 1
what should I do?